# Django model validation, pass current value to function?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to validate an expected IP value in my Django model as per the below:

```
dmvpn_dsl = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', verbose_name="DMVPN DSL IP", \
            validators=[validate_dmvpn_ip('','172.16.100.')], blank=True, null=True)
```

and in my functions i have

```
def validate_dmvpn_ip(value,subnet):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    if subnet not in value or value != '0.0.0.0':
        raise ValidationError(u'Invalid IP address, please check corrent octects have been assigned')
```

i just need to pass the current value to the function to check it, but am not sure how to set this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not to move subnet into validation function if it's hardcoded anyway? Then you can have just validators=[validate_dmvpn_ip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing `validators=[validate_dmvpn_ip('','172.16.100.')]`, you end up with the return value of calling the validation function as the validator (which is `validators=[None]` because you're not returning anything). It looks like you're trying to create a customizable validation function. For that you'll need to write a function that returns a another:

```
def validate_dmvpn_ip(subnet):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

    def validator(value):
        if subnet not in value or value != '0.0.0.0':
            raise ValidationError('Invalid IP address, please check corrent octects have been assigned')

    return validator
```

And you use it like so:

```
# outside model:
main_validator = validate_dmvpn_ip('172.16.100.')
main_validator.__name__ = 'main_validator'
main_validator.__module__ = 'path.to.this.module'

# inside model
dmvpn_dsl = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', verbose_name="DMVPN DSL IP", \
    validators=[main_validator], blank=True, null=True)
```

The outer function returns another function that takes a value to validate, but still has access to the subnet to validate against.

Notice how I'm signing the validator to another variable and assigning the `__name__` and `__module__` attributes. While this is normally not needed, django needs to be able to refer to the validator directly for migration purposes, and a returned function is not assigned anywhere. Of course if you only have one such validator, you can hardcode the subnet and avoid this mess:

```
def validate_dmvpn_ip(value):
    subnet = '172.16.100.'
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

    if subnet not in value or value != '0.0.0.0':
        raise ValidationError('Invalid IP address, please check corrent octects have been assigned')
```

and

```
dmvpn_dsl = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', verbose_name="DMVPN DSL IP", \
    validators=[validate_dmvpn_ip], blank=True, null=True)
```

To learn more about nested functions (closures), take a look at [decorators in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/5113242) which are basically this + special `@` syntax.

Comment: Thanks!, the path.to.this.module value, I'm not sure what i need to set this to? i will use this validator for multiple subnet validations, which is why i couldn't hard code it, but thank you for the explanations of it all, it helps!

Comment: It's just the path to the current module. In fact, I think you can just set it to `__name__` which is the magic variable containing the value you want.

Comment: dmvpn_dsl = validate_dmvpn_ip('172.16.100.')
dmvpn_dsl.__name__ = 'dmvpn_dsl'
dmvpn_dsl.__module__ = dmvpn_dsl.__name__ gives, __name__ must be set to a string

Comment: I meant `new_validator.__module__ = __name__`.

Comment: its working, but i think my logic statement is wrong, if subnet not in value or value != '0.0.0.0': is returning false if the subnet is 172.16.100. or 0.0.0.0 I'm trying to allow either of those values